# Doubt about application of stability criteria

Tags: control-system, control-theory

I have only seen systems with this transfer function treated in stability criteria with this general form:

$$\frac{KG(s)}{1\pm KG(s)}$$ so the $$\lvert H(s)\rvert =1$$

Is it possible to apply criteria with H(s) distinct of 1? Or must I do some transformation beforehand?

Comment: Normally, the system TF is assumed in the form: \$\frac{KG(s)}{1+KG(s)H(s)}\$, and there is no such restriction on \$H(s)\$. Give a link to the website that you are quoting from

Comment: cranck, do you expect that we should guess what you mean with H(s)? At least, you should show us an equation not only a simple expression.

Comment: This is only valid for systems with **Unity feedback path** if your systems feedback path has a value that is not equal to one then the system transfer function should be $$
\frac{KG(s)}{1+H(s) *KG(s)}
$$

Comment: Can you tell us which "stability criteria" are you talking about? Certainly all I know are applicable to H(s) distinct from 1.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume G(s) is strictly positive thus:
$$
\frac{KG(s)}{1+KG(s)}
$$
$$H(s) = 1$$
is a closed loop negative feedback system where it is assumed that H(s) which is the feedback component which is equal to 1.

We cannot substitute the plus sign for a minus sign which would make it a positive feedback system and therefore make it unstable.

$$
\frac{KG(s)}{1+K H(s)G(s)}
$$
$$ H(s)\neq 1 $$

For a system to be BIBO stable it must satisfy the magnitude and angle criteria. Which relates to the poles in the s-plane of the closed loop system.

Basically if you look a Root Locus diagram of a system all the poles should be in the left half plane and the phase plot should be within \$ \pm\pi\$ but thats not strictly true. A system can have range for which K the system is stable.

[image: diagram]